# tense combined present with past

Tags: tense, modal-verbs, conditional-constructions

> If I were her, I would have killed him months ago.  [[englishforum]](http://www.englishforums.com/English/IfIWereHimIWouldHave/bdxzjv/post.htm)

A person asks whether the expression can be acceptable. In my mother tongue, that also can be a way of saying. In English, is it a proper saying?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is indeed exactly the right way to construct an *IF...THEN* expression with a *counterfactual* (a ‘condition contrary to fact’)  in the *IF* clause:

1. For your *IF* clause, you employ the ‘past subjunctive’ (or whatever your particular grammatical sect chooses to call it); this is the basic past form of your verb, without personal inflection — in this case, *were*.
2. For your *THEN* clause, you start with the past form of a modal verb to mark the act as hypothetical: *would* ...
3. ... together with the ‘bare infinitive’ of your lexical verb, which would be *kill*, except that ...
4. ... in your case  you want to say not that you *would kill* in the present or future, but that this hypothetical act of violence would by now be an already accomplished fact. Accordingly, you **backshift** the infinitive *kill* into the past by employing the bare *perfect infinitive*: *have* + the past participle of your lexical verb, *killed*.

Answer (score 3):

The answer at [englishforums.com](http://www.englishforums.com/English/IfIWereHimIWouldHave/bdxzjv/post.htm) suggests that forms like  “If I were him, I would do...”  and  “If I had been him, I would have done...” are legitimate, and that form “If I were him, I would have done...”, while commonly heard, may be questionable.

That might be technically correct – I can't quite say – and in reviewing [the subjunctive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subjunctive_mood#English) in English I was unable to tell for certain.  Here in the USA I hear a vast variety of subjunctive forms and the form “If I were him, I would have done...” seems to me clear and understandable rather than wrong.

*Digression:* The problem I have with  “If I had been her, I would have killed him months ago” or “If I had been him, I would have done ...” is that they seem to pile a second counter-factual on top of the first counter-factual: they suggest that for a while I had been her or him (which is the first counter-factual), and in that while did some action, and after that (when the  *had been* phase ended) changed back to myself.  One or the other of those changes does not seem entirely natural to me.

Comment: *If I had been her* is the canonical backshift of *if I were her*. The  perfect construction with the past participle is employed to carry the past sense (since you can't backshift the past form *were* any farther), and the auxiliary *have* is cast in the 'subjunctive past' form *had* in order to carry the counterfactual sense. It would be more clearly parallel if you wrote "If I had been her I would have killed him months before."

Comment: If it was two old spinsters reminiscing about the time many decades earlier when one of them had turned down a suitor, the other might reasonably say *"If I'd have been you, I'd have married him"*. That seems a lot more appropriate than *"If I were you I'd have married him"* to me. But OP's example doesn't need to explicitly force the contrafactual postulate further back in time, so it's better as it is.

Comment: ...also (I know this'll make some cringe) - I'd never actually expand *"I'd"* there in normal speech. But if I was somehow forced to, I'd probably come out with *"If I **had** have been..."*, rather than *"If I **would** have been..."*

Comment: @FumbleFinger But why would you say either, rather than *If I'd been you*?

Comment: @StoneyB: Why indeed? Why, if I type in **if id known** to a Google Chrome "incognito" window (which prevents the results from being skewed by any of my previous searches) are two of the first four results for ***If I Knew** You Were Comin' I'd've Baked a Cake*. I guess the shorter form fits the "metre" of the song better, but presumably Google acts like that because a lot of people (when they're not actually *singing* it) remember the words differently. It feels to me as if the longer form in OP's example emphasises the contrafactuality more, but maybe that's just a personal feeling.

Comment: This confusion, of course, is caused by referring to the *were* form as "past subjunctive", though it is neither past nor a form of the subjunctive *be*; this is made worse by attempting to prescribe a correspondence between two proposed subjunctive forms and specific tenses, when that correspondence is not generally observed in actual usage.